# Does CakePHP have built-in functions to check for MySQL injections?

Tags: php, cakephp, sql-injection

Does CakePHP check inputs to see if they are valid and not injections? If not, how would I go about implementing functions to check inputs? Most of Cake's processes are done behind the scenes, so I'm unsure of where I would do that.

Answer (score 4):

CakePHP's ORM functionality automatically cleans up any input to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: …unless noted otherwise, see for example `updateAll()` http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sanitize class in the controller to prevent against sql injections, specifically the escape method.

To give a quick example for posted input:

```
if(!empty($this->data)
{
    App::import('Sanitize');
    $this->data['Model']['dirtyInput'] = Sanitize::escape($this->data['Model']['dirtyInput', 'default');
}
```

Also, check out the clean method for a way to clean both HTML and sql injections from your whole `$this->data` array

Comment: the link you've given for data sanitization is outdated. Please change it